# makefile error "Makefile:307: *** first argument to 'word' function must be greater than 0. Stop."

Tags: makefile

I was building a quantum chemistry program called `GAMESS` and there was an error in makefile: `307: *** first argument to 'word' function must be greater than 0. Stop.` I didn't touch anything.

This is 307 line:

```
$(foreach idx,$(shell seq $$(($(words $(MODULES_DD)) - 1))),$(eval $(call OBJ_template,$(word $(shell echo $$(( $(idx)+1 )) ),$(MODULES_DD)),$(word $(idx),$(MODULES_DD)))))
```

I've tried everything that came up in `GAMESS` README, but I only get this error from the MAKE command.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Is it Debian or Ubuntu GNU/Linux?  You can try this to see if it helps: `make SHELL=/bin/bash`.  This makefile is not portable to systems where `/bin/sh` is not bash.